# Not able to get Environment variable in Ubuntu 11.10 (earlier set in ~/.bashrc) using getenv() - from within a application development tool

Tags: ubuntu, environment-variables

We are editing ~/.bashrc with command: `/home/user> sudo gedit .bashrc`

Comment: Command used to set the variable? Can you use the terminal command line to read the variable?

Comment: Are you exporting the variable: `export VARIABLE=value`?

Answer (score 0):

If you set a variable in ~/.bashrc, this file has to be sourced again; typically by logging in again.

If you do not wish to permanently set this variable, set it in the terminal, without editing ~/.bashrc.

In any case, don't forget to use `export`.